# Open Source Linux Server Projects

Tags: java, c++, linux, open-source, enterprise

I'm interested in researching and trying to contribute to an open source project.  Since I run a linux desktop, there are many open source projects I'm familiar with, and I've contributed a little to some of them.  I find these projects, simply because I have a need for them.  Other than that, I have done a lot in game development, as I have found this interesting.

However, the programs I run, and those that enterprise businesses run are quite different: I assume.  I would really like to look at something which is used widely by businesses or organizations (unlike my side scroller).  I haven't really come across much enterprise development as I'm still in university and my side job is just managing apache servers.
My first pick was apache httpd server, but it seems to be written in C.  I'm looking for something written in java/c++.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Awesome question! You may already know this, but Apache is not just the web server, there are *lots* of projects that Apache maintains, like Cassandra for example.

Comment: what is your kind of interests? you need to answer for this question and after you can looking for current open source projects at google code, distrowatch(select distr -> select package -> go to the official site of project)

Comment: Question should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com - This is not a programming question per se, doesn't fit in there.

Answer (score 4):

Some Java based open source projects that might be of interest, have large communities and are commonly used in business:

- Eclipse (IDE and tools)
- Apache Commons (general purpose libraries)
- Netty (Networking library)
- OpenJDK (The open source Java implementation itself)
- JBoss (Application server)
- Play framework (Web framework)
- Clojure (modern Lisp-derived language on-top of the JVM)
- Hadoop (big data processing)

One word of advice - pick something that you are personally interested in / passionate about. You will then have a lot more fun, get a greater sense of satisfaction and probably be able to make a much more meaningful contribution as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things of the top of my head

Have a look at Apache website few of their products are java based.

- Tomcat : web app server
- Solr : enterprise search engine

CMS front their is

- Liferay : java based content management system
- dotCMS : never used it but think its meant to be quite good